# How to make an object randomly spawn inside of the stage only

Tags: actionscript-3

My stage size is 640 x 1136

I want to spawn my objects randomly but only inside of the stage.

I used this

```
object.x = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
```

How can I make the x position spawn within the stage area?

Comment: Replace `stageHeight` in you code with `stageWidth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want a "random in range" function [like the one here](http://snipplr.com/view/7326/as3-random-range/) 
(included below).

However, if you are doing a game you may not be satisfied with the result of randomly spawning objects (e.g. objects piling up on each other, etc.) and want to exert more control. Lots of ways to be clever with that – like defining a set of regions or quadrants, picking one of those randomly and then generating random coordinates within that region, or having an array of defined "good" points and randomly selected from it. Actual randomness is often less interesting than the idea or appearance of randomness.

```
public function randRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number {
   return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

TOMATO answer is the same as what you actually do so it's not really helpful. What you need to do is account for the object size. If you have an object that is at maximum 100 pixel wide then:

```
var size:Number = object.width; 
object.x = size + Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth - size * 2);
```

This make sure the object spawn on the x axis inside the stage x axis. Same operation needs to be repeated for the y axis of course.